# A continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, with $m > n$,

Tags: general-topology

Consider some continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, with $m > n$.  For notation, $\mathbf{Y} = g(\mathbf{X})$ where ${\bf X} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf Y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$.  We can say also write $Y_i = g_i(\mathbf{X})$ for each individual output, with $g_i$ being a continuous function.

What conditions would we require to be able to express at least one of the output variables, say $Y_m$ as a function of the other outputs instead? Wlog say $Y_m =h(Y_1,...Y_{m-1})$, for some continuous function $h$.

Let $Y_{\bf n} = (Y_1,...,Y_n) = (g_1({\bf X}),...,g_n({\bf X})) = g_{\bf n}({\bf X})$.  For example, if $g_{\bf n}$ is bijective then we know there is an inverse such that $\mathbf{X} = g_{\bf n}^{-1}({\bf Y}_{\bf n})$.  We could therefore say $Y_k = g_k(g_{\bf n}^{-1}({\bf Y}_{\bf n}))$,$\forall k > n$.  However it seems to me that $g_{\bf n}$ being bijective is quite restrictive.  It seems intuitive to me the fact that we are mapping into a larger space means our output be some manifold with a smaller dimensionality than $m$, but I'm not entirely sure how to see this, if it is true.

edit:  Fixed some notation errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of introducing $g_{\bf n}({\bf X})$ which is nothing else than $g({\bf X})$ and $Y_{\bf n}$ which is nothing else than $\bf Y$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, ${\bf Y}_{\bf n}$ would be a subset of ${\bf Y}$, not the same.  I want to know when I can write at least one of the outputs $Y_i$ as strictly a function of the other outputs and not ${\bf X}$.  I use $g_{\bf n}({\bf X})$ to highlight an example.  If $g_{\bf n}({\bf X})$ is bijective then we for $Y_k$, $k>n$, can be expressed as a function of the ${\bf Y}$'s as shown.

Comment: You are right, it has only the first $n$ coordinates.

Comment: Right. Is there a definitive way to see this must be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer directly depends not on the map $g$, but on its image $Z=g(\Bbb R^n)$. Indeed, let $\pi_m:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^{m-1}$ and $p_m:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R$ be projections, $\pi_m(Y_1,\dots,Y_m)=(Y_1, \dots,Y_{m-1})$ and $p_m(Y_1,\dots,Y_m)=Y_m$ for each $Y=(Y_1,\dots,Y_m)\in\Bbb R^m$. If there exists a function $h:\pi_m(Z)\to\Bbb R$ such that $Y_m=h\pi_m(Y)$ for each $Y\in Z$ then a restriction $\pi_m|Z$ is injective. Conversely, if  a map $\pi_m|Z$ is injective then we can put  $h(Y’)=p_m((\pi_m|Z)^{-1}(Y’))$ for each point $Y’\in\pi_m(Z)$.

Thus $h$ is a unique map from $\pi_m(Z)$ to $\Bbb R$ such that $p_m|Z=h\circ(\pi_m|Z)$. We claim that the map $h$ is continuous iff the map $\pi_m|Z$ is open onto image, that is $(\pi_m|Z)(V)$ is open in $\pi_m(Z)$ for each open subset $V$ of $Z$. Indeed, assume that the map $\pi_m|Z$ is open onto image. Let $U\subset R$ be any open set. Then a set

$$h^{-1}(U)=\{ Y’\in\pi_m(Z): p_m((\pi_m|Z)^{-1}(Y’))\in U\}=$$ $$\{Y’\in\pi_m(Z): (\pi_m|Z)^{-1}(Y’)\in p_m^{-1}(U)\}=(\pi_m|Z)(p_m^{-1}(U))$$

is open in  $\pi_m(Z)$. Conversely, assume that the map $h$ is continuous. Let $V$ be any open subset of $Z$. Then a set

$$(\pi_m|Z)(V)=\{Y’\in \pi_m(Z): h(Y’)\in V\}=h^{-1}(V),$$

is open in $\pi_m(Z)$.

Finally we remark that this condition does not always hold because we can easily construct an embedding $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$ such that projection $\pi_{3}|g(\Bbb R)$ is injective, but not open onto image.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  What does the notation $\pi_m|Z$ represent?  Let me see if I understand correctly.  A condition to show this is that the projection $\pi_m$, which maps each $(Y_1,...,Y_m)$ to $(Y_1,...,Y_{m-1})$, is injective and we can find some function $h$ which maps $\pi_m({\bf Y})$ onto $Y_m$?

Comment: @J.Doe $\pi_m|Z$ is the restriction of the map $\pi_m$ on the set $Z$, that is $\pi_m|Z$ is defined on $Z$ and 
$(\pi_m|Z)(Y)=\pi_m(Y)$ for each $Y\in Z$. We showed that there exists a function $h:\pi_m(Z)\to\Bbb R$ such that $Y_m=h\pi_m(Y)$ for each $Y\in Z$ if and only if a restriction $\pi_m|Z$ is injective.

Comment: Ah, I see, the notation means to restrict to the image of $g$, Z.  So, knowing that the projection is injective is sufficient.  Great, thank you!

Comment: @J.Doe $\pi_m|Z$ directly restricts not the image of $\pi_m$, but its domain (to $Z$).

Comment: Right, restrict the domain of $\pi_m$ to be the image of $g$.  My original comment was confusing.  Thanks again!